# Unable to play openload videos under Iframe Sandbox allow script

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Unable to play openload videos under Iframe Sandbox allow script

My Code :

```
 <iframe sandbox="allow-scripts" scrolling="no"
 src="https://oload.stream/embed/kxDLfFZqpX0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, they've put a mechanism against it. 
**sandbox="allow-scripts"** would block their ads :)